# sendUserActionEvent() returned Error In Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having an error which says :

> 2019-02-08 15:52:45.844 28896-28896/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess -
>   Process is Whitelisted 2019-02-08 15:52:45.846 28896-28896/?
>   E/libpersona: scanKnoxPersonas 2019-02-08 15:52:45.846 28896-28896/?
>   E/libpersona: Couldn't open the File -
>   /data/system/users/0/personalist.xml - No such file or directory
>   2019-02-08 15:53:12.280 28896-28896/com.example.servicees
>   E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() returned.

while  trying to launch the given code to my phone Samsung Galaxy J6 . I am coding in Android Studio and using email and password sign up method in Firebase . Could someone tell me a solution? Thanking You in advance.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText etName, etService, etDes, etCost, etContact, etPass, etEmail;
    Button offer;
    CountryCodePicker ccp;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        etName = findViewById(R.id.enterName);
        etService = findViewById(R.id.enterService);
        etDes = findViewById(R.id.enterDescription);
        etCost = findViewById(R.id.enterCost);
        etContact = findViewById(R.id.enterContact);
        etPass = findViewById(R.id.enterPassword);
        etEmail = findViewById(R.id.enterEmail);
        ccp = findViewById(R.id.ccpLogin);

        ccp.registerCarrierNumberEditText(etContact);

        offer = findViewById(R.id.offerBtn);

        mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        offer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /*final String putName=etName.getText().toString();
                final String putService=etService.getText().toString();
                final String putDes=etDes.getText().toString();
                final String putCost=etCost.getText().toString();*/
                final String putEmail=etEmail.getText().toString();
                final String putPass=etPass.getText().toString();

                //final String fullNumber = ccp.getFullNumberWithPlus();

                //final String key=fullNumber+putEmail;

                if(notEmpty()){
                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(putEmail, putPass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            final String putName=etName.getText().toString();
                            final String putService=etService.getText().toString();
                            final String putDes=etDes.getText().toString();
                            final String putCost=etCost.getText().toString();
                            final String putEmail=etEmail.getText().toString();
                            final String putPass=etPass.getText().toString();

                            final String fullNumber = ccp.getFullNumberWithPlus();
                            User user = new User(putName, putService, putDes, putCost,  fullNumber, putPass);
                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(putEmail).setValue(user);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Registered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "All Fields Are Required", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }


    public boolean notEmpty() {
        Boolean checker;
        String checkEmName = etName.getText().toString();
        String checkEmService = etService.getText().toString();
        String checkEmDes = etDes.getText().toString();
        String checkEmCost = etCost.getText().toString();
        String fullNumberCh = ccp.getFullNumberWithPlus();
        String checkEmEmail = etEmail.getText().toString();
        String checkEmPass = etPass.getText().toString();
        if (checkEmName.isEmpty() || checkEmService.isEmpty() || checkEmDes.isEmpty() || checkEmCost.isEmpty() || fullNumberCh.isEmpty() || checkEmEmail.isEmpty() || checkEmPass.isEmpty())
            checker = false;
        else
            checker = true;
        return checker;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am having a different error you can check it for yourself. Only the question looks apparently same.